# Laravel get most out of the database

Tags: php, laravel-4, tracker

I'm having a tracker in `Laravel 4` and I was wondering, how can I get the 'most' from my table.

So want I want is to have the day that had the most visitors.

My table structure looks like this:

[image: Structure]

So, my controller looks like this:

```
public function index()
    {    
        $begin = date('Y-m-01');
        $end = date('Y-m-t');

        $visits = Tracker::selectRaw('date, count(ip)')->groupBy('date')->whereRaw("date between '$begin' and '$end'")->get();

        //get total visits per month
        $get_visits = Visitor::whereRaw("date between '$begin' and '$end'")->count();

        // get average visits
        // transform dates to DateTime objects (we need the number of days between $begin and $end)
        $begin = new \DateTime($begin);
        $end = new \DateTime('now');
        $diff = $end->diff($begin); // creates a DateInterval object
        $days = (int)$diff->format('%a'); // %a  -->  days
        $average_visits = $get_visits / $days;


        return View::make('admin.home.index')->with('stats', $visits)
                                             ->with('get_visits', $get_visits)
                                             ->with('average_visits', $average_visits);

    }
```

What I want as an output:

> We had the most visitors on 18/06/2015 (542 visitors)

For example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **SELECT** the date **ORDER BY** the amount of visitors **DESCENDING** and **LIMIT** by 1. This is basic mysql. How to use this in laravel, is in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries).

Order by desc:

```
->orderBy('visits', 'desc')
```

Limit:

```
->take(1)
```

My example query is based on a system that has a column which counts the visits(which your structure doesn't have). So let me help you with your structure.

You want to have it by date so you basically **GROUP BY** date:

```
->groupBy('date')
```

From this query you want to have the amount of rows that belong to that date. So you use **COUNT**:

```
->count()
```

This is all based on that you know stuff about queries. *This is all according to the query builder.*

Comment: Yes, I do count all my visitors per month... But I want overall the max, you understand?

Comment: @RobinR You want the date where you had the most visitors right?

Comment: @RobinR Yes. My answer gives you everything you need. Basically: Select date and the count of all the records grouped by the date ordered by the count of all the records grouped by the date DESC LIMIT 1.

Comment: Could you maybe make an example for me? (in RMO Laravel query?)

Comment: @RobinR I will, when Im home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80915/discussion-between-robin-r-and-loko).

Comment: After a bit struggeling, I found the solution with @Loko. Thanks! This is the solution: `Visitor::selectRaw('count(*), date')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('count(*)', 'desc')->first()`

Comment: @RobinR If you want, you can edit it in the answer or I can do it.